# Rails multiple namespaces for one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

I need to be able to add some routes to one or more **dynamic** paths.

For example `paths = [ "foo/news", "bar/news" ]`. Both need to go to the same routes.

Should be something like this:

```
paths.each do |path|
  namespace path, module: "news" do
    root :to => "welcome#index"
    resources :articles
  end
end
```

But it gives me an error:

```
rake aborted!
Invalid route name: 'foo/news'
```

I tried many different things, most of them fail on starting the server, and some work but only give me good routes for the first path.

Anyone did something like this before?

I want to be able to use paths also, so when im in `'bar/news'`:

`news_article_path( @artice )` would give me `bar/news/articles/1` (instead of `foo/news/articles/1`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the '/news' part to the loop. Try this:

```
paths = [ "foo", "bar" ]

paths.each do |path|
  namespace path, module: "news" do
    namespace 'news', module: false do
      root :to => "welcome#index"
      resources :articles
    end
  end
end
```